# 14.04 LTS - Nvidia 331 Dual Monitors not working any more after updating

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

When using the X Server Nouvea Display Drivers my dual monitors works perfectly fine.  However it sometimes crashes so i decided to change the display drivers to the the latest NVIDIA 331.38 driver for the GTX 660 i have on my computer.

The monitors i have is a

1. Samsung which is plugged into the GPU VGA socket.
2. An Acer which is plugged into the MOBO VGA socket.

After the upgrade to the 331.38 Nvidia drivers i have no more crashes however only the samsung monitor which is plugged into the GPU is working. Is there any way i can fix this?

Also forgot to mention that when i boot up ubuntu the ACER second monitor connected to the mobo shows the loading screen for Ubuntu but does not boot up to the Desktop, just sticks at the loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you have not connected both monitors to the GTX660 ?

Can you open the nvidia X server configuration GUI, check both monitors are listed, are enabled and are positioned side by side.